# Which data use to shortlist promising models?

Tags: data-science, theory

After performing the data preparation step (data cleaning, feature selection, feature engineering...):

- Should I shortlist the promising models by feeding them with the dataset that is the result of the data preparation step?
- Or should I just use the scaled and encoded version of the original dataset?
- Both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to predict the outcome. if you can infer the outcome based on the feature engineering , selection and other EDA activities. As Andrew NG say, go ahead and train the model first as a baseline.

as long as your model is not overfitting or underfitting - you choose any one of the above.

Comment: I think I'm getting the point. Does this have to do with the No Free Lunch Theorem?

Comment: Yup, true. even if you take datasets (for learners) like iris or titanic dataset, same applies